# Karate runner: How to add arguments to runner - pass password

Tags: java, maven, karate

I have been using Karate in my previous company and got right the setup but in my new project I'm struggling to Run Karate through runner.

1. When setting the project up, I didn't get the karate.jar which usually is the default in Karate Runner's settings.
2. I would like to pass the password argument so I don't have it hardcoded in my tests

In karate.properties I have:

```
function fn() {
  var env = karate.env; // get system property 'karate.env'
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
  if (!env) {
    env = 'dev';
  }
  var config = {
    authUrl: 'https://exampleauthurl.com',
    password: karate.properties['password']
    
  }
```

In settings>Karate Runner > Karate Jar: Command line Args I have:

```
mvn test-compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.intuit.karate.Main -Dexec.args=-d -Dexec.classpathScope=test -Dpassword=MyPassword
```

When clicking on Karate:Run on top of my scenario I get:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.229 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-16T10:29:31+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix '/Users/user/Documents/Automation/UI/api-tests/src/test/java/feature/Explore.feature' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/user/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

If I tick the option "Karate Runner > Karate Cli: Override Karate Runner" tests run perfectly but I can't pass the argument of password in the settings so that I don't need to type it every time.

Running through command line using

```
mvn test -Dpassword=MyPassword
```

works perfectly!
So I wanted to add this argument for password:  -Dpassword=mypassword in the Karate Runner > Karate Jar: Command line args.
[image: Karate Runner Settings]
But since I don't have karate.jar in my project, When I click on Karate:Run on top of the scenario, it doesn't run the tests
[image: Karate:Run]
Have gone through tons of docs and stackoverlow answers, nothing helped so far.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think the karate runner supports this yet https://github.com/kirksl/karate-runner

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the past project I've managed to do it in command line jar runner. Passing karate.properties in karate-config.js and in command line jar passing the value for those arguments. 
How do I generate a jar then to be able to use this runner?

Comment: speaking for myself, I don't understand your question

Comment: Hey, you're right, my question might sound confusing.

Comment: Tried to all some more things but not sure if that helps. Will try to work my way around on this and see if I find a way to generate this karate.jar file. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to set this up, so I'm sharing an answer here in case somebody else needs it.

So if I need to pass an argument in the karate runner so that I don't need to pass it constantly in the CLI, e.g. via the command

```
mvn test -D password=mypassword
```

I can add it in `Karate Runner` >> Karate Cli: Command Line Args :
`-Dexec.password=mypassword`

That way, when we click on a button `"Karate:Run"` on top of the Scenario, it will be executed with this argument.